# Entity framework navigation property loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF with Fluent API.

So I have two classes with a one to many relationship

```
public class Room {
    //list of properties

    public List<Image> Images {get; set; }
}

public class Image {
    public Room Room {get; set; }
}
```

If I first ask for the rooms

```
var rooms = ctx.Rooms.ToList();
```

And then I ask for the images

```
var images = ctx.Images.ToList();
```

And then I explore the rooms Collection, I see that each room has her list of images, even If i didn't Included nor Projected images in the first query.

How does this happen?

**EDIT** 
I know that two queries are performed, and that's exactly what I want, since the real world first query is more complex and a lot of navigation property are loaded, I don't want the images get involved in the joins.

I just want to understand how does the code above can work, I expected that I had to manually join the two lists, but somehow this is done automatically.

Comment: Are you viewing the object in the debugger? if so it will go get the values. If you write some code to get the values and just run a test does that still have values present?

Comment: Google for "entity framework lazy loading". I don't know if you necessarily want to disable it, but just understand it. If you try to access a property or list which hasn't been loaded yet, another query will be performed and therefore another hit on your database.

Comment: A simple unit test would allow me to explain the behaviour. We need more info.

Comment: This line: `public List<Image> Images {get; set; }` defines the relationship between `Room` and `Image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All children under the parent entity, are those you loaded using `var images = ctx.Images.ToList();` Exactly themselves; Its because of relation between parent and child that you defined using code first conventions or api, so they are listed there.

I suppose that you have disabled lazy loading, and so you should not worry about performance because they don't load twice. The are those images that you load yourself expelicitly.

---

Here is a simple test to get the concept. I have a context having `Parent` entity and `Child` entity with a relation defined between them:

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var parents = db.Parents.ToList();
//Shows False, So childs are not loaded.
Console.WriteLine(parents.Any(x => x.Childs.Count() > 0).ToString());

var childs = db.Childs.ToList();
//Shows True, We didn't loads Parents again, and EF only relates them.
Console.WriteLine(parents.Any(x => x.Childs.Count() > 0).ToString());
```

Comment: does entity framework really make that link? He has committed both queries? had they been `IQueryable` then maybe...?

Comment: If you disable lazy loading you will see those children are still there and its because of relation. EF does't load them again, don't worry. It only relates them to parent. You may find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32276630/3110834) helpful.

Comment: I disagree, if he wrote an integration test and ran `var rooms = ctx.Rooms.ToList();` all children would be null?

Comment: With LazyLoading diabled if you first run `var rooms = ctx.Rooms.ToList();` all children will be null/default.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for reply, I'm surprised I don't have to explicitly join the two lists in order to create a room list with their associated images. Is this the default behavior of EF regardless lazy loading being enabled or not?

Comment: @Heberda naturally if you just run the first query without including that navigation property, the navigation property will be null.

Comment: You didn't joined them but you have created a relation between them (using conventions or maybe explicitly using apis). But don't worry about the performance, the are not loaded twice.

Comment: @Stuntman You didn't join them but you have created a relation between them (using code first conventions or maybe  explicitly) and the context relates them after you load them, even if you load them separately, you should not worry about the performance of this, because it doesn't load them twice, it only related them when find them in context.

Comment: Yes that is clear. I should have included that scenario in my answer :)

Comment: @Stuntman Thanks for feedback, by the way, while you can only mark one post as answer, but you can kindly vote up as many answer as you find helpful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the answer :) You can also vote for good questions:)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and explain the scenario with some tests...

```
public class Room {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Image> Images {get; set; }
}
public class Image {
    public Room Room {get; set; }
}
```

I'd expect all tests to pass...

```
[TestMethod]
public void NoLazyLoadingAndNoEagerLoading()
{
  var _db = new dbContext();
  var rooms = _db.Rooms.ToList();
  //All images will be null
  Assert.IsFalse(rooms.Any(x => x.Images != null));
  _db.Dispose();
}

[TestMethod]
public void NoLazyLoadingAndNoEagerLoading()
{
  var _db = new dbContext();
  var rooms = _db.Rooms.Include(x => x.Images).ToList();   
  //We have eager loaded them in the first query.
  Assert.IsTrue(rooms.Any(x => x.Images != null));
  _db.Dispose();

}
```

Also with Lazy Loading on and the following model tweak

```
public class Room {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Image> Images {get; set; }
}

public void NoLazyLoadingAndNoEagerLoading()
{
  var _db = new dbContext();
  var rooms = _db.Rooms.ToList();
  //Now lazy loading should kick in,
  //Entity framework will make more calls to the db and return Images
  Assert.IsFalse(rooms.Any(x => x.Images != null));
  _db.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: See the simple test that I added to answer and let me know if you still disagree? :)

Comment: Oh yes I agree, I think we were both answering the question in different ways.