# Entity Framework 7 Core disable auto loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am not use **virtual** navigation property

I want manually specify fields to load

```cs
IQueryable<ScheduleModel> q = _db.Schedules;
q = q.Include(x => x.ElementItem); <-- load ElementItem
q = q.Include(x => x.ScheduleHours); <-- load collection
```

But EF7 load (or assign) ScheduleHours[0..x].ElementItem because ElementItem with same Id loaded in first Include()

After serialization in Json I have big model.

How disable auto loading not specified fields?

Comment: Make your navigation properties `virtual`, they won't be loaded unless you explicitly load them using `Include`.

Comment: EF Core doesn't support lazy loading yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881169/navigation-property-should-be-virtual-not-required-in-ef-core

Comment: @BradleyUffner, virtual doesn't work in EF Core

Comment: @Alex It was working for me yesterday, `virtual` properties were not loading unless I called `Include` on them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data#eager-explicit-and-lazy-loading-of-related-data

Comment: You confuse lazy loading with relationship fixup. EF will populate navigation properties with entities it has loaded into the context.

Comment: @Alex load not specified fields is LazyLoading? I don`t want load any not specified properties

Comment: @Alex There are way to disable auto populate?

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov Read carefully the Gert Arnold's comment. Also the **Tip** in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the EF Core documentation. Shortly, no, you can't disable that behavior because it's "by design".

Comment: This is about EF5, but as for me, it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31107876/861716

Comment: but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data#use-multiple-queries

Comment: q = q.AsNoTracking(); - was solve problem